# How can i delete all the image meta data in cloudinary ?

Tags: cloudinary

Is there a way to delete all the metadata related to images in cloudinary?

I want to delete - faces, colors, exif, image_metadata, context, pages, phash, coordinates etc.

Is there an API to do so?

Answer (score 2):

Image meta-data is automatically stripped whenever Cloudinary applies a transformation on an image.

If you want to strip the metadata from an original image, you can apply the flag 'force_strip' upon upload as an incoming transformation.|

Here is a ruby sample on how to apply the force strip to an original on upload:

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload("sample.jpg", :transformation => [{:flags => "force_strip"}])
```

Comment: But, what if I don't want to delete it at the time of upload?